# Azure AD user provisioning custom attributes

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning

When mapping a Azure Active Directory Attribute with "customappsso Attribute" like in the image below for user provisioning, the custom fields are not being send by the POST request
when creating the user in the target system. Why is this happening? The attributes which are not submitted on the POST requests are "imeto" , "prezimeto"

[image]

The custom attributes are submitted on a second PATCH request via "Add" operation and regardless of the response back its never taken in to the consideration which means the same PATCH request will be submitted on next provisioning by demand or the normal cycle of provisioning. How can i alter this behavior the customappsso to be in the first POST request?

Comment: Please share how you define the `createUser` method.

Comment: It looks like that your "Create User" doesn't fill in values for "imeto" and "prezimeto" .

Comment: The issue is that i never receive those parameter on the first POST request for creating the user on first provisioning. so its obvious the response will not contain them. "imeto" and "prezimeto" are customappsso attributes , mapped to a value from the Azure AD. On provisioning the user(POST request) they are never being submitted,

Comment: So the issue should be from the AAD backend side right? Looks like It is not something I can check out from the surface. We suggest you contact Azure support.

Comment: All ready did but there is no answer at all :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/396323/why-arent-custom-attributes-provisioned-on-post-re.html